# How to read integers from a file with both integers and letters

Tags: java

I am trying to read in a file, while only getting the integers and keeping count of each integer. The code I have so far is:

```
while(inputFile.hasNext()){
    file1_String=inputFile.next();
    file1_length=file1_length+1;
    System.out.println(file1_length);
}
```

the output is:

```
13 c v b 25 34 x x 67 56 10 a a 20 27 2 a s 5 1 45 59
```

but that is just the content of the file. How do I get rid of the letters while importing it into java?

Answer (score 0):

If you want file1_length to contain the total number of items in the file while only assigning the numbers to file1_String, try this:

```
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    file1_String = inputFile.nextInt();
    file1_length++;
}
System.out.println(file1_length);
```

On the other hand, if you want the letters to be ignored totally, try this:

```
while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
     file1_String = inputFile.nextInt();
     file1_length++;
}
System.out.println(file1_length);
```

EDIT: Try this instead:

```
while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
    if (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
        file1_String = inputFile.nextInt();
        file1_length++;
    }
 }
 System.out.println(file1_length);
```

Comment: I am trying to ignore the letters completely, when I typed that code into my file it only returned the first number in the file which is 13, but I don't know why

Comment: I suppose I should have tested that first - I was certain it'd work, though. I added another possibility but then tested that and found it has the same problem. Sorry! I'll let you know if I figure out a solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
file1_String=file1_String.replaceAll("[^0-9]"," ");
file1_length=file1_length+ file1_String.split("\\s+").length;
```

Comment: Do I just put this inside the while loop?